# The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate

Tags: c#, soap, public-key-encryption

I am a newbe with soap and have been given an assignment to create a soap client with message encryption and password authentication to interface with a service written in java.
The catch is the encryption is one way (client to server).  The responses are not encrypted and are basically pass/fail. The certificate will not have the private key.

In the code listed below if I include the  definition I get the failure 'The private key is not present in the X.509 certificate.'

If I remove it I get the failure 'The service certificate is not provided for target 'http://localhost:65182/services/ConnectTest'. Specify a service certificate in ClientCredentials.'

How to it tell it that I will not have service credentials and it will not need to decrypt the response?

```
    private void SendEncrypted_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectTest.ConnectWebServiceClient client = new ConnectTest.ConnectWebServiceClient();


            PasswordDigestBehavior behavior = new PasswordDigestBehavior("joe", "password");
            client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);

            XmlDocument data = GetXmlData();
            XmlNode payload = data.SelectSingleNode("xml");
            string result;

            result = client.postTransactionXML(payload.InnerXml);
            textBox1.Text = result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ex.Message;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                textBox1.Text += "\n" + ex.InnerException;
        }
    }



    <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:65182/services/ConnectTest"
          behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="SOAPServiceSoapBinding" contract="ConnectTest.ConnectWebService"
          name="ConnectWebPort">
        <identity>
          <dns value="Unknown" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SOAPServiceSoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                openTimeout="00:00:20" receiveTimeout="00:00:30" sendTimeout="00:00:40"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="1000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
                useDefaultWebProxy="false">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Digest" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
        <clientCredentials>
          <clientCertificate findValue="foo.com" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          <serviceCertificate>
            <defaultCertificate findValue="foo.com" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
          </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```